# Select difference depending on criteria

Tags: postgresql

Hope you can help me with one select statement.
I need to select only the records based on criteria but only when duplicates are detected. The criteria is No_Type='Custom'

Example of table data:

```
Product  |  Component  |  Detail  |  Stock  |  No_Type
-------------------------------------------------------
Brick       Powder        Grain      12        General
Brick       Water         Plain      34        General
Brick       Additives     A95        54        General
Brick       Powder        Grain      67        Custom
Brick       Water         Plain      55        Custom
Brick       Additives     A95        43        Custom
Box         Wood          Oak         1        General
Box         Nails         Steel       2        General
```

Result is based on detecting duplicate values for columns (Product, Component, Details) and if detected, select the records where under column No_Type is stated with 'Custom'.

What I would need as a result is:

```
Product  |  Component  |  Detail  |  Stock  |  No_Type
-------------------------------------------------------
Brick       Powder        Grain      67        Custom
Brick       Water         Plain      55        Custom
Brick       Additives     A95        43        Custom
Box         Wood          Oak         1        General
Box         Nails         Steel       2        General
```

There is no ID fields in the table, only what is here.
I'm using Postgresql.

Comment: This is confusing. In the first line Stock is 67 but there are two values that are not duplicates 67 and 12. Also No_Type is not always always 'Custom' in your expected results. Should the query look for duplicate values in Stock?

Comment: I see the error in my concept. Made a adjustment to it. Only for Product, Component and Detail columns should duplicates be detected.

Comment: If for some records only 'General' No_Type is present, then those records are fine and should be in the results. Thank you for your comment.